# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound 404 error response

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, model-view-controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

the index file where I added a form and action "output"

```
<html>
<body>  <form action="output">
        <input type="text" name="t1"></br> <input type="text" name="t2"></br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The servlet is configured as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.guni.Controllers"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

sampleController.java

```
package com.guni;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class sampleController { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/output", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String karna()
    {
        return "sampleOutput.jsp";
    }
}
```

I am trying to execute a form GET with submit button. the Submit button does not respond any thing. The web page gives me 404 error. Any body has any idea.I am using eclipse 2019 and tomcat9. i am trying to create a web application in maven using spring 4.0

When i run the project it gives me the bellow error 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
   No mapping for GET /demoMVC/output

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is registered to accept GET requests on `/output`, while you're performing a GET request on `/demoMVC/output`. Either modify your `@RequestMapping`value to `/demoMVC/output`, or change the URL you're calling in your browser.

Furthermore, in many cases an `InternalResourceViewResolver` is configured to return the name of the JSP file without the `.jsp` suffix. Assuming you've created a file named `sampleOutput.jsp`, adjust your `karna()` method to return `"sampleOutput"` instead of `"sampleOutput.jsp"`. If this does not work, would you be able to you post your `InternalResourceViewResolver` configuration?